# How to prettyprint as hex a pyasn1 octect string that is printed as ascii

Tags: python, asn.1, pyasn1

I have some `pyasn1` octect string objects defined like this:

```
LInfo.componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(namedtype.NamedType('XXX', univ.OctetString().subtype(subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(2, 2)).subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 0)))
```

When I decode the `asn.1` using `pyasn.1` library, it translates the value to its ascii representation, for example I get "`&/`" but I need to show the numeric value, in hex representation. For example in this case instead of `&/` I need `262F`.
Obviously I can extract `&/` or whatever I find in there and convert it manually, like:

```
value.asOctects().encode("HEX")
```

but then I can't write it back in the field in this format.

Is there an easy way to manipulate the object before printing it out in such a way that I can see `262F` in the final pretty print without modifying the `asn.1` definition (that I can't change as it is given to me)?

Comment: If you want to modify `OctetString` representation of the `XXX` element or do you want to modify BER serialization of the whole data structure?

Comment: I can't modify what I receive in input, I just have to provide a decoder that shows the content in a readable format. In this case this particular field must appear as "262F" instead it shows &/. The only things that I have access to are the classes.py file that I have generated (using the asn1ate tool) from the asn.1 definition file that was provided to me (and that I cannot change). I was wondering if there was a way to modify the content of the field to "trick" the default prettyprint to show it with the hex representation.

Comment: I can add that I have several other fields declared as Octet String, that are used to carry digit information and they work fine, I have in printout strings in the form: 0x0172ce02. If I could obtain something like that also for the fields that are used to carry a true numeric value, like obtaining 0x262f that would still be perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to subclass the `OctetString` class, override its `prettyPrint` method then register your new class with the decoder. What your `prettyPrint` returns is what ultimately goes out into print.

```
from pyasn1.codec.ber import decoder
from pyasn1.type import univ


class OctetString(univ.OctetString):
    def prettyPrint(self):
        return self._value


class OctetStringDecoder(decoder.OctetStringDecoder):
    protoComponent = OctetString('')


decoder.tagMap[OctetString.tagSet] = OctetStringDecoder()
decoder.typeMap[OctetString.typeId] = OctetStringDecoder()
```

Here is [the original code](https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1/blob/master/pyasn1/type/univ.py#L919).

Comment: Thanks!I just had to remove the line if x < 32 or x > 126: that prevented hexification when the value fell into ASCII range.